# Remove last comma from range search in BST C++

Tags: c++

I have the code for range search in a BST:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class node{
   public:
      int data;
      node *left;
      node *right;
};
void nodesInRange(node *root, int k1, int k2){
   if ( NULL == root )
      return;
   if ( k1 < root->data )
      nodesInRange(root->left, k1, k2);
   if ( k1 <= root->data && k2 >= root->data )
      cout<<root->data<<",";
   if ( k2 > root->data )
      nodesInRange(root->right, k1, k2);
}
node* insert(int data){
   node *temp = new node();
   temp->data = data;
   temp->left = NULL;
   temp->right = NULL;
   return temp;
}
int main(){
   node *root = new node();
   int k1 = 12, k2 = 25;
   root = insert(20);
   root->left = insert(10);
   root->right = insert(24);
   root->left->left = insert(8);
   root->left->right = insert(15);
   root->right->right = insert(32);
   cout<<”The values of node within the range are\t”;
   nodesInRange(root, k1, k2);
   return 0;
}
```

The code`cout<<root->data<<",";` result  `15,20,24,`
But I want to print `15,20,24`, how do I do that?

I've tried using `string.erase()` or insert comma before each entry except the first, but they don't work in this case and they would just remove all commas in the result like `152024`.

Comment: You probably do not find the proposed duplicate helpful. Please [edit] to explain why this is not a duplicate. E.g. "the proposed duplicate does not help with output from a recursive function". Which is probably a design problem.... Also, please explain why something like a boolean "your are potentially the right-most" parameter is not the solution to your problem this side of a design change.

Comment: You seem to have incorrect characters in your [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You could let `nodesInRange` take a parameter that tells it if there's been any output prior to the call. As soon as there's been any output, the state will be passed on to the subsequent calls.

Example:

```cpp
bool nodesInRange(node *root, int k1, int k2, bool got_output = false) {    
    if (root) {
        if (k1 < root->data)
            got_output = nodesInRange(root->left, k1, k2, got_output);

        if (k1 <= root->data && k2 >= root->data) {
            // only print a comma if there's been some output prior to this
            if(got_output) std::cout << ", ";
            else got_output = true;

            std::cout << root->data;            
        }

        if (k2 > root->data)
            got_output = nodesInRange(root->right, k1, k2, got_output);
    }
    return got_output;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fsqr7ePGb)

Comment: I have a feeling that this can be done just with a parameter, i.e. still `void`. But I currently do not have code to put next to my mouth.... ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch  :-) Yeah, one could take it by reference instead - but that would change first call in `main`. The user would then need to supply an initialized `bool` - but that's ok too I guess.

Comment: Not what I meant. I am totally with you, that the perfect solution does not need a change to the call from `main()`. I am thinking of a peek at the left subnode, but only that, nothing recursive. I will be back if I find time to make code implement my gut feeling. Until then (and even beyond) yours is a useful answer to me.

Comment: If you are interested, I convinced myself that with peeking only into one node, but not recursively, I cannot do it. This is because e.g. the right subnode is guaranteed to be larger than the current node, but not to be the smallest larger node in the tree. So, there won't be code to go with my mouth. ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch :-) Ok, it was worth a try!

Answer (score 1):

IMO best approach is to generalize code. Separate iteration from IO operation.

```cpp
void forEachInRange(node* root, int k1, int k2, std::function<void(int data)> f)
{
   if ( NULL == root )
      return;
   if ( k1 < root->data )
      forEachInRange(root->left, k1, k2, f);
   if ( k1 <= root->data && k2 >= root->data )
      f(root->data);
   if ( k2 > root->data )
      forEachInRange(root->right, k1, k2, f);
}
```

Then handling separator becomes quite trivial:

```cpp
void printInRange(node* root, int k1, int k2)
{
    std::string sep;
    forEachInRange(root, k1, k2, [&sep](int data) {
        std::cout << sep << data; 
        sep = ",";
    });
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qed1ndeed

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Change the logic of your output functions to omit the trailing `','` for the last element (e.g. if the right member has no members).
2. Or do not write the output directly to `std::cout` but to [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream). Then create a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) that excludes the last character of `std::ostringstream::str()`. Output that view to `std::cout`.

Option 1 requires some careful thinking, while option 2 is fairly simple and straightforward to implement but at the cost of requiring additional memory and time to run.

Comment: Please explain how a function which currently only ever looks at a single node in the tree can tell whether it is the last in the output or not. The recursive attribute is important for that.

Comment: @Yunnosch You probably have to carry around some state across all recursive calls. It depends on the domain how to best pass that around.

Comment: Yes, thanks for confirming my comment on the question and the other answer...

Comment: @Yunnosch For example, you already know the upper limit in the form of `k2`. You can figure out in the function whether there is a right node that still satisfies that limit.

Comment: Given the current answers, there are at least 3 options ;-)

Comment: @wovano I disagree. Both other answers are variations on option 1: Have some persistent state outside the function. They just do it differently.